# How to fetch all the values that should be translated for a particular profile / user?

Tags: translation, translation-workbench

I would like to prepare an stf file that would contains only the keys that must be translated for a particular user / profile. This stf file would contain the keys of all the components that the user can access from the UI.

I believe this would limit the number of labels that should be translated.

Any suggestion to achieve this would be appreciated.

Comment: Last I knew translations were global per language, is this no longer the case ?

Comment: you are right, they are. But you see if I would want to implement a new language, the translation workbench would give me thousands of labels across the entire application that should be translated. However, in actual only the values that are actually visible on the user's screen should be translated. For Example: I would not want to translate hundreds of picklist values that are not accessible to the end user at all. That is why I am looking for a way to extract only the components that are actually visible from the UI.